# Mysql: Select When Joined Field Equals Condition

Tags: php, mysql, join

**Image Table**

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
| image_id | image_user_id | profile_image | image_status |
+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
|        1 |             1 |    834098.png |         live |
|        2 |             2 |    347903.jpg |      pending |
|        3 |             3 |    447903.jpg |      pending |
+----------+---------------+---------------+--------------+
```

**Comment Table**

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
| comment_id | comment_user_id | text          |
+------------+---------------------------------+
|          1 |               1 | great article |
|          2 |               2 |       not bad |
|          3 |               3 |         lorem |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT
    profile_image,
    comment_id
FROM comment
LEFT JOIN image ON image_user_id = comment_user_id
WHERE image_status = 'live'
LIMIT 7
```

The above code only reads comments when the relating `image_pending` field is set to `live`. How could I change the code to make it read `profile_image` when the `image_status` is `live`?

The above code would output:

```
array( 'profile_image' => '834098.png', 'comment_id' => 1 )
```

It should output:

```
array(
    array( 'profile_image' => '834098.png', 'comment_id' => 1 )
    array( 'comment_id' => 2 )
    array( 'comment_id' => 3 )
)
```

Comment: Couldn't understand your question. Can you please clarify what do you really want to have different in that query? and i don't see an image_pending field.

Comment: sorry, I elaborated further with an example. I hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this that you want?

```sql
SELECT
    profile_image,
    comment_id
FROM comment
LEFT JOIN image ON image_user_id = comment_user_id AND image_status = 'live'
LIMIT 7
```

Will return:

```
PROFILE_IMAGE   COMMENT_ID
834098.png          1
(null)              2
(null)              3
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97c32/2)</kbd>

You were filtering the result using image_status = 'live' in the where clause, when you want to filter the join condition instead.

Comment: Thank you Filipe Silva, I did not know that a condition could be added to a join; ignorance on my part. Thank you for the code example :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your where clause ans use case to check the status

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN image_status = 'live' THEN 
    profile_image ELSE NULL END ) profile_image ,
    comment_id
FROM comment
LEFT JOIN image ON image_user_id = comment_user_id
LIMIT 7
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97c32/3)

Comment: An eloquent solution to the problem dianuj, thank you for the example.